# Laravel Storing into databse (error null value)

Tags: php, laravel

I want to get the consultation id and input it into the drug_prescription table. I have alrdy tested the $consultation_id variable with an echo and there is a correct value in it. But I am unable to input that variable into the drug_prescription table.

Below are the code for the controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $this->validate($request,[
        'client_id' => 'required',
        'staff_id' => 'required',
        'diagnosis' => 'required',
    ]);

    //Create Post
    $consultation = new consultation;
    $consultation->client_id = $request->input('client_id');
    $consultation->staff_id = $request->input('staff_id');
    $consultation->client_complaints = $request->input('client_complaints');
    $consultation->observations = $request->input('observations');
    $consultation->physical_abnormalities = $request->input('physical_abnormalities');
    $consultation->diagnosis = $request->input('diagnosis');
    $consultation->remarks = $request->input('remarks');
    $consultation->save();

$client_id = $request->client_id;

    $consultation = DB::table('consultations')
    ->where('client_id', '=', $client_id)
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->take(1)
    ->get();

    // var_dump($consultation);

    $client_id = $request->client_id;
    $consultation_id = $consultation[0]->id;

    $count = $request->count;
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
        $quantity = 'quantity' . $i;
        $quantityStatus = $request->$quantity;
        if($quantityStatus!=NULL){
            $drug_prescription = new drug_prescription;
            $drug_prescription->client_id = $request->input('client_id');
            $drug_prescription->drug_id = $request->input('drug' . $i);
            $drug_prescription->consultation_id = $request->input($consultation_id) ;
            $drug_prescription->amount_perday = $request->input('amount_perday' . $i);
            $drug_prescription->amount_ofday = $request->input('amount_ofday' . $i);
            $drug_prescription->quantity = $request->input('quantity'. $i);
            $drug_prescription->price = $request->input('price'. $i);
            $drug_prescription->save();
        }
    }
    // return redirect('/appointment')->with('success', 'Consultation Infomation Added');
    // dd($request->all());
}
```

Comment: So what happens? Do you get any error message?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Yes I got an error message `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'consultation_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `drug_prescriptions` (`client_id`, `drug_id`, `consultation_id`, `amount_perday`, `amount_ofday`, `quantity`, `price`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (1, 1, , 2, 1, 2, 4, 2018-08-02 09:33:34, 2018-08-02 09:33:34))`

Comment: Please update your question to include the error message instead of in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$drug_prescription->consultation_id = $request->input($consultation_id) ;` should be

`$drug_prescription->consultation_id = $consultation_id;`

since its value doesn't come from the `request`'s input but from within your code.

Comment: Not a problem. And thank _you_ for accepting this as answer if it solved your problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$drug_prescription->consultation_id = $request->input($consultation_id) ;

$drug_prescription->consultation_id = $consultation_id;
```

I hope it will work.